# Pandas: how to filter rows of a column to get alternating signs between every two consecutive cells?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[-0.1, -0.2, 0.2, -0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6]})
df
    a
0   -0.1
1   -0.2
2   0.2
3   -0.1
4   0.1
5   0.5
6   0.6
```

I would like to filter the rows of column `a` such that the signs of two consecutive cells are alternating.

For example, if I want to start with a positive number in the first cell, then the filtered dataframe would look like this

```
    a
2   0.2
3   -0.1
4   0.1
```

Alternatively, if I want to start with a negative number, the dataframe would look like this

```
    a
0   -0.1
2   0.2
3   -0.1
4   0.1
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

The solution I have so far for a dataframe that starts with a positive number is

```
df_long_first = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['a'])
for i in range(len(df)):
    cur_val = df['a'].iloc[i]
    cur_sign = np.where(cur_val > 0, "p", "n")
    if i == 0:
        df_long_first = df_long_first.append({"a" : cur_val}, ignore_index = True)
    else:
        last_sign = np.where(df_long_first['a'].iloc[-1] > 0, "p", "n")
        if last_sign == cur_sign:
            continue
        else:
            df_long_first = df_long_first.append({"a" : cur_val}, ignore_index = True)
            
        
df_long_first
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could think of at the moment. The function takes a 1d array and iterates over its indices and values. It will remove/add a given symbol to a value with an even/odd index. By default it remove the symbol if a value has a symbol and an even index. The start_no_sym default param can be used to change the pattern. It returns a 1d array.

```
def alternate(col, symbol, start_no_sym=True):
    alternated = []

    # no symbol, symbol pattern  
    if start_no_sym:
        for idx, val in enumerate(col):
            # remove symbol from even index vals
            if idx % 2 == 0 and symbol in val: alternated.append(val[1:])
            # if odd idx val has no symbol, add it
            elif idx % 2 != 0 and symbol not in val: alternated.append(f'{symbol}{val}')
            else: alternated.append(val)
    
    # symbol, no symbol pattern
    else:
        for idx, val in enumerate(col):
            # add symbol to even index vals with no symbol
            if idx % 2 == 0 and symbol not in val: alternated.append(f'{symbol}{val}')
            # if odd index val has a symbol, remove it
            elif idx % 2 != 0 and symbol in val: alternated.append(val[1:])
            else: alternated.append(val)

    return alternated

# test
print(alternate(['<3', "9", '<0', '<6', '<2', '8', '1', '6'], '<'))
```

Comment: I just reread your question and think I misunderstood it. If you are only dealing with positive and negative values then the if statements should be checking if `val` is less than or greater than 0, rather than checking if `symbol` is in `val`. The rest of logic works out though.